# Ajax CodeIgniter form submit hide and show new view

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm a newbie to ajax and trying to integrate it in to my CodeIgniter app. Basically, when the form is successful I would like the original template to be hidden and the new one shown? It currently displays both, how could I amend my code? Thanks in advance!

I have tried adding a redirect to my controller with no such luck :(

view:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>part-two",
      $("form").serialize(),
      function(result){
         $("#error_message").html(result);
      }, "html" 
   );       
});
```

controller:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
   echo validation_errors();        
} else {
  echo "success";
  $data['content'] = "part_two";
  $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some of the template view? Are you using an if statement to switch between each form whilst using a single view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think that I know what you want...

View html markup:

```
<div class="container">
<form id="form">
    ...
</form>
    <div class="error_message">
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
$.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>part-two",
  $("form").serialize(),
  function(result){

     // clear the content and assing the result
     $("#form").remove();
     $("#error_message").html(result);
  }, "html" 
);       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant help you so much. Would you please use firebug to see received data of post request ?

Since both are displaying so i think post request is okay. Problem is in your view file.